# error: no matching function for call to ‘sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::connectNotify(const char*&)’

Tags: c++, qt, archlinux, ros

I'm using ROS Indigo with Arch Linux ARM and i'm trying to install the package **ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp** from AUR.

But then pops up the following error:

```
[ 85%] Compiling generated code for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp: In member function ‘void sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::disconnectNotify(const char*)’:
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:183:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::disconnectNotify(const char*&)’
         qt_gui_cpp::RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::disconnectNotify(a0);
                                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qthread.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/QThread:1,
                 from sipAPIlibqt_gui_cpp_sip.h:14,
                 from siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:7:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:436:18: note: candidate: virtual void QObject::disconnectNotify(const QMetaMethod&)
     virtual void disconnectNotify(const QMetaMethod &signal);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:436:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char*’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp: In member function ‘void sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::connectNotify(const char*)’:
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:201:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::connectNotify(const char*&)’
         qt_gui_cpp::RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::connectNotify(a0);
                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qthread.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/QThread:1,
                 from sipAPIlibqt_gui_cpp_sip.h:14,
                 from siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:7:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:435:18: note: candidate: virtual void QObject::connectNotify(const QMetaMethod&)
     virtual void connectNotify(const QMetaMethod &signal);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:435:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char*’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp: In member function ‘void sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::sipProtectVirt_connectNotify(bool, const char*)’:
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:432:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::connectNotify(const char*&)’
     (sipSelfWasArg ? QObject::connectNotify(a0) : connectNotify(a0));
                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qthread.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/QThread:1,
                 from sipAPIlibqt_gui_cpp_sip.h:14,
                 from siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:7:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:435:18: note: candidate: virtual void QObject::connectNotify(const QMetaMethod&)
     virtual void connectNotify(const QMetaMethod &signal);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:435:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char*’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp: In member function ‘void sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::sipProtectVirt_disconnectNotify(bool, const char*)’:
/home/hiago/packages/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/build/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:437:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘sipqt_gui_cpp_RosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins::disconnectNotify(const char*&)’
     (sipSelfWasArg ? QObject::disconnectNotify(a0) : disconnectNotify(a0));
                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qthread.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/QThread:1,
                 from sipAPIlibqt_gui_cpp_sip.h:14,
                 from siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:7:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:436:18: note: candidate: virtual void QObject::disconnectNotify(const QMetaMethod&)
     virtual void disconnectNotify(const QMetaMethod &signal);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:436:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char*’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
make[3]: *** [Makefile:18: siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:61: devel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui_cpp/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.so] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:375: src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I've been googling for the last 4 hours and haven't gotten a solution, nor even a clue. All i've found that possibly is related to this error doesn't helped too much.

I've gone through the **qobject.h** file aiming to solve the problem but no success ( i'm very newbie on C++, so i've done my best... )

I'm strongly needing help.

If i haven't provided enough information, please tell me, then i will provide any other information or piece of code needed to help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package (as all ROS Indigo packages) expect Qt4. It seems the code generated by sip-dev is indeed for Qt4 (where `connectNotify(const char * signal)` was used) but you are compiling it for Qt5 (where the function was replaced with `connectNotify(const QMetaMethod & signal)`) - hence the  error message.

One solution could be to simply remove Qt5 / downgrade to Qt4. Alternatively see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt on how to select the default Qt version.

Comment: P.S.: If your use of Arch is not set in stone (for whatever reason), it may be easier to switch to Ubuntu 14.04 as here all versions are "just right" for ROS Indigo and won't change.

Comment: I removed the package `qt5-base` and `qt4` is already installed. Then i did run **Makepkg** again but now it's showing a new  error:
`In file included from siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipqt_gui_cppRosPluginlibPluginProvider_ForPlugins.cpp:7:0:
sipAPIlibqt_gui_cpp_sip.h:13:21: fatal error: QMetaType: No such file or directory
 #include <QMetaType>
                     ^`.

Comment: I did set the environmet variable `export QT_SELECT=4` (as shown in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt ) but it hasn't gone for nothing. It seems even doing these changes, the build is not getting aware it should use qt4 instead of qt5. I don't know where to go now.

Comment: Check that eg. sip-dev is also the qt4 version. Generally, consider using Ubuntu 14.04, this will make life much easier as you will stumble upon these kinds of problem all the time when using a bleeding edge distro such as Arch.

Comment: I'm really wondering using Ubuntu. Anyway, i could solve this problem removing **qt5** and downloading the package again. But when building i get a brand new error this time related to Python. I'll create a new question about this new error as now this one here is "solved". Thank you somehow.

Comment: Hey @dseifert I could solve the whole problem and compile the package **ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp** succesfully. For all of you users who are facing this problem or are going to eventually, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593473/problems-during-compilation-of-ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp-in-arch-linux-arm where i'm describing all the steps i've taken to solve it.
Should i paste the steps in this question here as well?